# Is there a performance penalty on using databases instead of schemas in a single PostgreSQL cluster?

Tags: postgresql, database-design, postgresql-performance

I m partitioning  my problem using a Domain-Driven Design approach. Several databases arise with low or null coupling.

In the long term they will be separate databases on separate hosts, horizontally scaled. However, currently I do not need/want such an expensive deployment. I just plan to run the whole thing on a single PostgreSQL cluster. The development environment is another clear situation where having a single cluster is desirable.

Authors as Chris Richardson recommend using schemas in the near term however, I have found this implies rewriting  part of the SQL code when logical replication is used to solve the couplings. I imagine he is using the term *schema* with MySQL in mind.
https://microservices.io/patterns/data/database-per-service.html

Using separate databases seem to be the perfect solution in terms of SQL code invariance but, does this imply a performance penalty on a sole cluster compared to a single database virtually segmented by schemas?

I have read this similar question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1152405/is-it-better-to-use-multiple-databases-with-one-schema-each-or-one-database-wit/1157008#1157008 but mine is clearly focused on performance penalty. I am clearly biased to segment the problem using databases from a logical point of view.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Example where schema are better than multiple databases](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/249132/example-where-schema-are-better-than-multiple-databases)

Comment: Thanks but, as I said, they will end up as separate dbs on separate hosts. Schemas ate not an option

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't need to join data from several databases, splitting the data into multiple databases is the cleaner solution, and there should be no performance disadvantages.

Comment: Thank you Laurenz. I suppose that no extra PG cluster processes are launched for every database, right?

Comment: Right. They also share the same cache.

Answer (score 1):

Yes. The main problem is that you can't reuse connections. Which means that you will have more connection, which means that you will use more memory.

OTOH separate DBs means that each DB stats will be smaller.

Comment: That need not be a problem. Each database will receive fewer requests, so you can use several smaller connection pools.

Comment: Thank you. I'm ok with that (having more connections). I was expecting something more painful, as having a bunch of separate processes per database or something like that.

Comment: Sure. You will have separate processes per database. For each connection, as always.

Comment: Yes, that is reasonable.